# Posting on friend's wall using facebook ios sdk dialog post is not appearing app description

Tags: iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

hello everyone I am posting on my friends wall using the dialog Facebook ios sdk. Everything is working fine I can see the post on my friend's wall when I visit facebook via my pc browser. But however when I am on ipad/iphone facebook app the description doesnot appear?